# click a menu item content to be displayed in the right side div in the same page without refresh?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am having a php template where i have a leftmenu as accordin jquery menu. In this menu i had menu items .When i click the menu item, page related to this menu item to be loaded into the div in the right side of the page without refresh.I[image: mypage] am giving you the screenshot of the page.

Can anyone help me in this regard,

Thank you in advance
Ramsai

here is the code of left menu.php

```
<div  id="leftmenu">
  <div class="urbangreymenu">
    <h3 class="headerbar"><a href="#">BREAST</a></h3>
     <ul class="submenu">
      **<li><a href="breast.php">Breast/a></li>**
      </ul>
    <h3 class="headerbar"><a href="#">CVS</a></h3>

    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">CHEST PAIN</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CHEST PAIN MASTER</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">DIZZINESS-VERTIGO-LOC</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">LOCAL-LEG-GENERALISED SWELLING</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SHORT OF BREATH(+PND)</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h3 class="headerbar"><a href="#">ENT</a></h3>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">EAR</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">NOSE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">THROAT</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h3 class="headerbar"><a href="#">GENERAL</a></h3>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">FATIGUE-MALAISE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FEVER</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SKIN RASH & PRURITIS</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h3 class="headerbar"><a href="#">GIT</a></h3>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">ABDOMINAL DISTENTION</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ABDOMINAL PAIN</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">BLACK STOOLS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONSTIPATION</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">DIARRHEA</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">NAUSEA-VOMITING</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h3 class="headerbar"><a href="#">NEUROLOGY</a></h3>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">APHASIA & SLURRED SPEECH</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">BALANCE-TREMORS-PARALYSIS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">HEADACHE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SEIZURES-MEMORY LOSS-CONFUSION</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">TINGLING-NUMBNESS</a></li>
    </ul>

     <h3 class="headerbar"><a href="#">PULMONARY</a></h3>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">COUGH</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is my loading code:

```
<div id ="content">
<script>
$.get('breast.php', function(data) {
$('.content').html(data);
});
</script>

</div>
```

When i click the menu item then the related page should come in that div

Thank you in advance,
Ramsai

Comment: You better need to give code than a snip

Comment: Why have you tagged php5 with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('#leftmenu').find('a[href*=".php"]').live('click', function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();

                            $.get($(this).attr('href'), function (data) {
                                $('.content').html(data);
                            });
                        });
        //Or

                    $('#leftmenu').find('a[href*=".php"][class*="MyWebLink"]').live('click', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
if(!$(this).hasClass('Alreadyloaded')){

                        var Url = $(this).attr('href');

                        $.ajax({
                            url: Url, type: 'Get', dataType: 'json',
                            //data: { value: $(this).data('value') },
                            success: function (data) {
                                $('.content').append(data);
    //Or
                                $('.content').prepend(data);

                                $(this).addClass('Alreadyloaded');
                            }
                        });
}
                    });
                    });
```

Comment: when i click the menu item the page related to this menu item to be loaded in the rightside ('.content') of the page without refresh?

Comment: my leftmenu is in leftmenu.php and the content div is in patient_account.php. I am calling leftmenu .php into patient_account.Will the above code works? and also is it correct find('a[href*=".php"]') or any correction to be made to this Also i have around 35 to 40 forms related to the menu items to be loaded into. Is it possible to load that many forms dynamically without refresh in same page?

Comment: $('.content').html(data); -> $('.content').append(data); or $('.content').prepend(data);

Comment: find('a[href*=".php"]') is this correct way or any modification is needed

Comment: it is correct way.. find('a[href*=".php"][class*="MyWebLink"]'). u can add class for link what u want to load..

Comment: :Thank you very much for your help .My head is blowing with this question. the document.ready function should be mentioned in my patient_account page or in leftmenu.php please give clarification to me.why because leftmenu.php is included in patient_account.php and the content to be displayed in patient_account.php Please Dont think otherwise.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11357/discussion-between-thulasiram-and-ramsai)

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem? Use [docs.jquery.com/Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

Comment: when i click the menu item the page related to this menu item to be loaded in the rightside of the page without refresh. Is there anyway to code in jquery