# How can I use something like ajax switch menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to do a web page (http://gianlucapetronzi.com/marcella/) with wordpress that it gives me the possibility to use the menu without refresh the page when i click on the menu link, but I have some problem.

I tried to do it with a js like this: [click a menu item content to be displayed in the right side div in the same page without refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613734/click-a-menu-item-content-to-be-displayed-in-the-right-side-div-in-the-same-page).
and with jquery.hide and jquery.show (changing the html code) but it doesn't work.

The real problem is that when I click the link inside the menu, it close and re-open itself , I think because of the refresh.

Is possible that the problem is that wordpress has 3 different file which generate a page? header.php, index.php or mypage.php and footer.php.

I download my menu from here: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/switchmenu.htm.

PS: if you want to try,  use the page: Home,architettura,55inch/60mq and centro parrocchiale, I didn't finish the other pages because of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you're using, they're reloading the page each time.

However, to get your example to work, you simply have to write code to grab the contents you want to display on the page (via a get for example) and then write it to a particular div.  You can avoid the reload by doing a jquery `.on click` handler rather than an `A:link`

There's a million different examples out there, here's just one:  http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Finally i found a wordpress plugin Advanced Ajax Page Loader 2.6.5 here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-ajax-page-loader/